# What happen when give value bigger than CHAR_MAX (127) to char

Tags: c++

```
char* c = new char[1];
c = { 128 };
```

When I using `Qt` debugger to display the contains of `c` , it shows `128`.

So tried another way:

```
c = 128;
```

also shows `128` in the debugger.

What happens in memory when assigning a value which bigger than the maximum range.

Comment: Undefined behaviour because it's a signed overflow

Comment: It depends. If `char` is signed then overflowing it will lead to *undefined behavior*. If `char` is unsigned, then that's okay. If a `char` is signed or unsigned is "implementation specified", i.e. it's up to the compiler.

Comment: Please!  No more!

Comment: @martin It seems you are in agony. Take it easy :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude & UKMonkey this is not signed overflow. Converting a non-representable value to a signed integer results in implementation defined value; not UB. Overflow happens during arithmetic operations.