# Is a char value set to CHAR_MAX guaranteed to wrap around to CHAR_MIN?

Tags: c, char, language-lawyer, standards, integer-overflow

My code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    char c = CHAR_MAX;
    c += 1;
    printf("CHAR_MIN=%d CHAR_MAX=%d c=%d (%c)\n", CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX, c, c);
}
```

Output:

```c
CHAR_MIN=-128 CHAR_MAX=127 c=-128 ()
```

We see that when we increment a `char` variable set to `CHAR_MAX`, it wraps around to `CHAR_MIN`. Is this behavior guaranteed? Or is it going to be undefined behavior or implementation-specified behavior? What does the C99 standard say about this?

[Note: [What happen when give value bigger than CHAR_MAX (127) to char](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48902396/1175080) or [C- why char c=129 will convert into -127?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20756626/1175080) does not address this question because they talk about assigning an out-of-range value not incrementing a value to an out-of-range value.]

Comment: An increment is an assignment.

Comment: It depends on whether the char is signed or unsigned. Overflow of signed integers is undefined behaviour. So the output can be anything.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question is twofold: Firstly, is

```
char c = CHAR_MAX;
c += 1;
```

evaluated differently from

```
char c = CHAR_MAX;
c = c + 1;
```

and the answer is *no it is not*, because [C11/C18 6.5.16.2p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.2p3):

> 3. A compound assignment of the form `E1 op = E2` is equivalent to the simple assignment expression `E1 = E1 op (E2)` except that the lvalue `E1` is evaluated only once, and with respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation of a compound assignment is a single evaluation. If `E1` has an atomic type, compound assignment is a read-modify-write operation with `memory_order_seq_cst` memory order semantics. 113)

Then, the question is what happens in `c = c + 1`. Here the operands to `+` undergo usual arithmetic conversions, and `c` and `1` are therefore promoted to `int`, unless a really wacky architecture requires that `char` is promoted to `unsigned int`. The calculation of `+` is then evaluated, and the result, of type `int`/`unsigned int` is converted back to `char` and stored in `c`.

There are **3** implementation-defined ways in which this can then be evaluated:

- `CHAR_MIN` is 0 and therefore `char` is unsigned.

  Either `char` is then promoted to `int` or `unsigned int` and if it is promoted to an `int`, then `CHAR_MAX + 1` will necessarily fit into an `int` too, and will not overflow, or if `unsigned int` it may fit or wrap around to zero. When the resulting value, which is numerically either `CHAR_MAX + 1` or `0` after modulo reduction, back to `c`, after modulo reduction it will become 0, i.e. `CHAR_MIN`
- Otherwise `char` is signed, then if `CHAR_MAX`  is smaller than `INT_MAX`, the result of `CHAR_MAX + 1` will fit an `int`, and the standard [C11/C18 6.3.1.3p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p3) applies to the conversion that happens upon *assignment*:

  > 3. Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.
- Or, **iff** `sizeof (int) == 1` **and** `char` is signed, then `char` is promoted to an `int`, and `CHAR_MAX == INT_MAX` => `CHAR_MAX + 1` will cause an integer overflow and the **behaviour will be undefined**.

I.e. the possible results are:

- If `char` is an unsigned integer type, the result is always `0`, i.e. `CHAR_MIN`.
- Otherwise `char` is a signed integer type, and the behaviour is implementation-defined/undefined:

  - `CHAR_MIN` or some other implementation-defined value,
  - an implementation-defined signal is raised, possibly terminating the program,
  - or the behaviour is undefined on some platforms where `sizeof (char) == sizeof (int)`.

---

All increment operations `c = c + 1`, `c += 1`, `c++` and `++c` have the same side effects on the same platform. The evaluated value of the expression `c++` will be the value of `c` before the increment; for the other three, it will be the value of `c` after the increment.

Comment: `sizeof(int) == 1` would require `CHAR_BITS >= 16`, right?

Comment: @sepp2k `<pedantic>`IDK about `CHAR_BITS` but `CHAR_BIT` would `>= 16</pedantic>`.

Comment: What if the code has `c++` instead of `c += 1`? Is the answer still implementation-defined?

Comment: `++c` is exactly equivalent to `c += 1`. `c++` is equivalent in side effects to that of `c += 1`, but the evaluated value will be different.

Comment: One more reason why `char` should always be unsigned by default.

Comment: @chqrlie I agree, unfortunately it might be just that it was signed by default because unsigned was later in the history, might be too difficult to change now on some cr*ppy systems due to sheer amount of broken programs expecting EOF to fit in a char..

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: indeed it is too late now, but it allows for some very counter intuitive behavior, such as `'0xff' == EOF` .

Comment: I think `int` is required to be capable of holding all values of `char`.  If a system can't address anything smaller than its natural `int` type, I think `char` would have to be signed.

Comment: A theoretical possibility not yet considered would be that `char` could be an unsigned quantity N==15 bits or larger, `int` could be two bytes long with N value bits, one sign bit, and N-1 padding bits, and `unsigned` could be two bytes long with N+1 value bits and N-1 padding bits.  On that implementation, incrementing a value equal to `CHAR_MAX` would yield UB even if `char` was unsigned.

Comment: Sometimes it is clear to  add a direct answer too: "Is a char value set to CHAR_MAX guaranteed to wrap around to CHAR_MIN?" -> No.